# Jquery - Change Option Value After Selection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to display different `<option>` *text* and *value* from a chosen `checkbox` using jquery Ajax. On my form, I have a two checkbox for user to choose price range. Example as below,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="1" id="ceo"> < RM 10,000 
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="2" id="bod"> < RM 200,000
```

If user choose `value='1'` or `value='2'`, the output of two select option value will change base on the selected checkbox.

```
//display application name
<select name="submited_by" id="submited_by">
  <option value="0">Choose Price Range</option>
</select>

//display name to approve application
<select name="hod" id="hod">
  <option value="0">Choose Price Range</option>
</select>
```

**Ajax to peform the change**

```
$("input[name='price_range']").click(function() {
    var price = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'DropdownValuesForm.php',
        data: { price : price }, 
        success: function(data){
            $('#submited_by').html(data)
        }
    }); 

});
```

**DropdownValuesForm.php**

```
<?php
require 'db_connection.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $price = $_POST['price'];
}

if($price == '< RM 10,000'){ 
    //do the Query

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $submited_by = $row['staff_id'];    
            $nama = $row['nama'];

            echo '<option value=" ' . $submited_by . ' ">' . $nama . '</option>';
        }   
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result);

} else {
    //do the Query

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $submited_id = $row['staff_id'];
            $nama_pemohon = $row['nama'];

            echo '<option value=" ' . $submited_id . ' ">' . $nama_pemohon . '</option>';
        }   
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

On my case, it will change for `<select name="submited_by">` only. Do I need to make another ajax function for the `<select name="hod" id="hod">` and make another page to get the value from database like `DropdownValuesForm.php`.

Comment: You only need one page to do all your ajax queries. You should make some sort of action-based system that runs functions or clas/methods on commands sent from the ajax.

Comment: thanks for the info @Rasclatt. Do you have an example or similar example like mine?

Comment: All you do is make a data attribute on the checkbox like `data-action="whatever"`, extract that value and send it along with the check value through your Ajax. It will tell your php what to do.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are trying to do, you really just need to stick with one ajax page that will dispatch instructions. See my answer (second half under *EDIT/JUST AS A SIDE*) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060278/success-message-not-displaying-using-jquery-ajax/39061331#39061331) to see how to implement a simple dispatcher. Using the dispatcher from that post, here is what this workflow would look like:

**Form checkboxes:**

```
<!-- Unless you need the form to submit a 1 or 2, it would be better to send 10,000 or 20,000 instead of 1 or 2 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="1" id="ceo" data-instructions='{"action":"get_price_range","value":"< RM 10,000","sendto":"#submited_by"}' class="ajax_trigger" />
<input type="checkbox" name="price_range" value="2" id="bod" data-instructions='{"action":"get_price_range","value":"< RM 20,000","sendto":"#hod"}' class="ajax_trigger" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var doc = $(this);
    // Create ajax instance (from other post, see that script)
    var Ajax = new AjaxEngine($);
    // If you trigger on a class, you can do ajax anywhere on your page
    doc.on('click', '.ajax_trigger', function() {
        // You will likely want to check first that the click is enabling
        // the checkbox or disabling it (check/uncheck) before you run the ajax
        // Extract the instructions
        var dataInstr = $(this).data('instructions');
        // Send the instructions
        Ajax.send(dataInstr,function(response) {
            // Use the extracted sendto to save to a spot on this page
            // It would be better to return json string to decode. This way
            // you can return instructions along with the html for further
            // dynamic processing...but this instance, this should do
            $(dataInstr.sendto).html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

**$_POST:**

Your post would then send:

```
Array(
    [action] => get_price_range
    [value] => < RM 10,000
    [sendto] => #submited_by
)
```

**XML:**

Using the other post as a guide, you can create an xml to point your dispatch to that spot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <ajax>
        <action>
            <get_price_range>
                <include>/actions/get_price_range.php</include>
            </get_price_range>
        </action>
    </ajax>
</config>
```

Your dispatch would then include this page into the call:

```
/actions/get_price_range.php
```

**/functions/getPriceOptions.php**

Put key scripts into functions (class/methods for even more flexibility) for portability and re-use.

```
<?php
/*
** @description  This will return your options
** @param $key [string] This is whatever you used to isolate the data in your sql call
** @param $db [resource] This is the mysqli connection that you need to run the query
*/
function getPriceOptions($key,$db)
    {
        ##################
        ## do the query ##
        ##################

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $submited_by = $row['staff_id'];    
                $nama        = $row['nama'];
                # You may want to just return data and not a view
                # the function will be more flexible that way
                $disp[]      = '<option value=" ' . $submited_by . ' ">' . $nama . '</option>';
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return (!empty($disp))? implode(PHP_EOL,$disp):'';
    }
```

**/actions/get_price_range.php**

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/db_connection.php');
# include the function
require_once(__DIR__.'/functions/getPriceOptions.php');
# Isolate the post
$price = $_POST['price'];
# Get the query key word/value to search your database
$key   = ($price == '< RM 10,000')? 'whatever' : 'otherwhatever';
# Write to the view
echo getPriceOptions($key,$db);
```

**DEMO:**

Here is a demo of all the integrating script from the linked post and the above. The example is slightly different because I don't have your table and I want to send back the post array so you can see that as well, but the end result is the same:

http://www.nubersoft.com/tester.php?example=39736539

Comment: Yeah if you have issues let me know.